# How to install pyinstaller on aix7.1

Tags: pyinstaller, zlib, aix

I want to install pyinstaller on aix7.1, but failed.

I have already installed zlib-devel.

This is the error message when installing pyinstaller:

```
-bash-4.2# python ./waf distclean all   

'distclean' finished successfully (0.203s)
'all' finished successfully (0.000s)
'distclean' finished successfully (0.000s)
Setting top to                           : /u02/py/pyinstaller-develop/bootloader 
Setting out to                           : /u02/py/pyinstaller-develop/bootloader/build 
Python Version                           : 2.7.10 (default, Jun 21 2016, 10:30:16) [C] 
Checking for 'xlc' (C compiler)          : not found 
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking size of pointer                 : 4 
Platform                                 : AIX-32bit detected based on compiler 
Checking for flags -maix32               : yes 
Checking for program '/usr/bin/strip'    : /usr/bin/strip 
Checking for program 'strip'             : /usr/bin/strip 
Checking for library dl                  : yes 
Checking for library m                   : yes 
Checking for library z                   : yes 
Checking for function unsetenv           : yes 
Checking for function mkdtemp            : yes 
'configure' finished successfully (2.248s)
'make_all' finished successfully (0.018s)
Waf: Entering directory `/u02/py/pyinstaller-develop/bootloader/build/debug'
[ 1/13] Compiling src/main.c
[ 2/13] Compiling src/pyi_archive.c
[ 3/13] Compiling src/pyi_global.c
[ 4/13] Compiling src/pyi_launch.c
[ 5/13] Compiling src/pyi_main.c
[ 6/13] Compiling src/pyi_path.c
[ 7/13] Compiling src/pyi_python.c
[ 8/13] Compiling src/pyi_python27_compat.c
[ 9/13] Compiling src/pyi_pythonlib.c
[10/13] Compiling src/pyi_utils.c
[11/13] Compiling src/pyi_win32_utils.c
[12/13] Linking build/debug/run_d
collect2: library libZ not found

Waf: Leaving directory `/u02/py/pyinstaller-develop/bootloader/build/debug'
Build failed
 -> task in 'run_d' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to display more information)
-bash-4.2# 
-bash-4.2# 
-bash-4.2# 
-bash-4.2# find / -name libz.so
/opt/freeware/lib/libz.so
/opt/freeware/lib64/libz.so
/usr/lib/libz.so
/usr/lib64/libz.so
-bash-4.2#
```

Comment: Also, as it says, `run with -v to display more information` and `library libZ not found` and `Checking for 'xlc' (C compiler): not found`. You're missing both of those.

Comment: [12/13] Linking build/debug/run_d
11:47:03 runner ['/usr/bin/gcc', '-maix32', '-Wl,-brtl', 'src/main.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_archive.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_global.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_launch.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_main.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_path.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_python.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_python27_compat.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_pythonlib.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_utils.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_win32_utils.c.1.o', '-o', '/u02/py/pyinstaller-develop/bootloader/build/debug/run_d', '-Wl,-bstatic', '-lZ', '-Wl,-bdynamic', '-ldl', '-lm']
collect2: library libZ not found

Comment: when i run with -v，it show like this
[12/13] Linking build/debug/run_d
11:47:03 runner ['/usr/bin/gcc', '-maix32', '-Wl,-brtl', 'src/main.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_archive.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_global.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_launch.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_main.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_path.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_python.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_python27_compat.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_pythonlib.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_utils.c.1.o', 'src/pyi_win32_utils.c.1.o', '-o', '/u02/py/pyinstaller-develop/bootloader/build/debug/run_d', '-Wl,-bstatic', '-lZ', '-Wl,-bdynamic', '-ldl', '-lm']
collect2: library libZ not found

Comment: What do you mean `-lZ`? Is it `-lz` misspelled?

Comment: when i copy the libz.a to libZ.a ,it passed!
cp /usr/lib/libz.a /usr/lib/libZ.a
But there have been some new errors：
[14/14] Processing build/debug/run_d
+ install /u02/py/pyinstaller-develop/PyInstaller/bootloader/AIX-32bit/run_d (from build/debug/run_d)
strip: run_d -- 0654-420 The file was already stripped as specified.

Waf: Leaving directory `/u02/py/pyinstaller-develop/bootloader/build/debug'
Build failed
 -> task in 'run_d' failed with exit status 255 (run with -v to display more information)
-bash-4.2#

Answer (score 0):

First, edit `bootloader/wscript` file

```
--- wscript.bak 2018-09-09 20:12:10.000000000 +0200
+++ wscript     2019-07-02 10:57:30.000000000 +0200
@@ -770,8 +770,9 @@
          staticlibs = []
          if ctx.env.DEST_OS == 'aix':
              # link statically with zlib
-             libs.remove('Z')
-             staticlibs.append('Z')
+             # libs.remove('Z')
+             # staticlibs.append('Z')
+             pass

          if ctx.options.boehmgc:
              libs.append('GC')
```

Then create a script named `/opt/freeware/bin/strip` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/strip "$@"
exit 0
```

Don't forget `chmod +x /opt/freeware/bin/strip`

Also there is a problem with function `mkdtemp`, to solve it do this:

```
export CPPFLAGS='-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700'
python ./waf -v all
```

Note: you should know that AIX is very problematic in itself, but combining it with *helping software* (like this waf) makes it worse. Additional reading: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html#Q0026